# Should I parse XML using JavaScript or use CSS to display it

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, parsing

I am building a Winform web browser. I have a `history.xml` file which stores history of the browser. I need to display that in the browser window so the user can click the hyperlink of the website and navigate. I want to use JavaScript to parse the XML file and display the content in table form. How do I parse XML using JS? I am not sure about what to use in this situation. I already have a good HTML page with CSS to display history. Please advice.

My XML file looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<browsing>
  <history date="08/10/2012">
    <url>http://www.google.ca/</url>
    <time>12:52 AM</time>
  </history>
  <history date="08/10/2012">
    <url>http://www.facebook.com/</url>
    <time>12:53 AM</time>
  </history>
  <history date="08/10/2012">
    <url>http://ca.msn.com/</url>
    <time>9:51 PM</time>
  </history>
</browsing>
```

Comment: Why not use `XSLT` to style it and show it as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery's $.get().

```
$.get("history.xml", function(xml) {
  $(xml).find("history:nth(0)").find("url").val(); // returns http://www.google.ca/
  $(xml).find("history:nth(1)").getAttribute("date"); // returns 08/10/2012
}, "xml");
```

EDIT: While i was writing this answer, your post was edited.  To display it in a table form, it might be easier just to use [XSLT](http://w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp).  It's specifically designed for styling XML.